# Sum of truncated normal random variable and normal random variable

Tags: statistics, probability

I'm wondering if there is a closed-form pdf of sum of "correlated" normal random variable and truncated normal random variable. I found a paper providing the pdf for "uncorrelated" case, but could find one for the correlated case which is of my interest.